# Magento: when to use Mage::getResourceModel() alone

Tags: magento

Is there any circumstances that would require a Magento developer to use `Mage::getResourceModel()`, apart from when using collections?

I have been developing for a while in Magento now and have yet to come across a circumstance where I need to use `Mage::getResourceModel()` on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using a model/resource model pair that doesn't fall into the standard CRUD pattern, and you want to directly call a public method of the resource model.

A few examples off this in the code base (off the top of my head)

```
Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
100:                $this->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
138:            $this->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());

Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Attribute/Set/Main.php
179:        $configurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')
191:            $nodeChildren = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
233:        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
243:        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getResourceModel` when you want to get only a resource model instance (also this is some kind of optimization for collections, but it's really stupid that collections are resouce models). For example, for getting resource model you may use:

```
Mage::getModel('my_module/path_to_resource_model');
```

This code creates the model with name `My_Module_Model_Path_To_Resource_Model`. But it's not the good solution because you may specify resource model class prefix inside config.xml (e.g. like in Mage_Cms):

```
............................................
        <models>
            <cms>
                <class>Mage_Cms_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>cms_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </cms>
            <cms_mysql4>
<!-- ----> --> <class>Mage_Cms_Model_Mysql</class>
............................................
```

But when you use `Mage::getResourceModel` the system reads resource model class prefix (and you will be able to change it in future). So, the first code snippet may be rewritten as:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('my_module/model');
```

Comment: Why is it "really stupid" that collections are accessed as resource models?

Comment: @benmarks because they are not resources. They are containers for business models, so it's not logical that collections are also resource models (so they are also business models in that meaning). There are few methods that reveals implementation of collections (e.g. `getSelect`) and it's not good. It had been better business models had  shared resource model with collections. And inside `load` method of abstract collection class should be something like `$this->getResource()->loadCollection($this);` (or `$this->getResource()->provideCollectionData(/* some arguments */);`)

Comment: @benmarks Also you can find a lot of mixed business and sql logic inside collections. So, that situation makes separation models between resource and business useless. Also you cann't change a resource from which collection will be loaded (you should write your own collection).